# changing for loop to lapply over several files

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, lapply

I have many csv files and I need to read all of them and perform some operations in the variables. I have used a “for loop”, but it is taking too long. I have searched many answers here and I know that lapply would be much more efficient, but I am not able to implement that. Could anyone help me please?
A file example is:

```
ID  Estimate       SE        avar    h2 
683 6.17E-02       1.226     1.11   0.19
52  -1.77E-02      1.278    1.11    0.19
```

I have almost 50 files in the same format, but with different names. What I want to do is to read all the files, create a variable called rel, which is: 1 -(SE^2)/avar. After that I want to subset the data based on the variable rel and write the new files. What I have tried is:

```
 myfiles <- list.files(pattern=".csv")

    for (j in 1:length(myfiles)) {
        this_file <- read.csv(myfiles[j], header = T)
        for (i in this_file) {
               for (k in 1:dim(this_file)){
              this_file["rel"] = 1-((this_file["SE"]*this_file["SE"])/this_file["avar"])
              this_file <- subset(this_file, this_file["rel"] >= 0.8*this_file["h2"])

      write.csv(this_file, file=this_file)
    }}}
```

I know it is pretty simple, but I am not getting it. Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you.
Paula.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do after reading each csv file.

Comment: Thank you @Metrics. I have done that.

Comment: When you say they have different names, do you mean the files or the columns in each file?

Comment: The files @Richard Scriven. It is like: cat.csv; dog.csv, etc. All the files have the same variable names (ID, Estimate, SE, avar and h2 ).

Comment: Okay, I'd recommend you send the subsetted data to a new file so you don't overwrite your original data

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do. I want to create other 50 new files and name them such as cat2.csv. Not sure yet how to do it tho. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you close.  I'll use a new vector of file names so we don't overwrite your current files.

```
myfiles <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

## make a vector of new file names 'cat*.csv' where * is 1:length(myfiles)
newfiles <- sprintf("cat%d.csv", seq_along(myfiles))

Map(function(x, y) {
        df <- read.table(x, header = TRUE)
        df$rel <- with(df, 1 - (SE^2 / avar))
        write.table(df[df$rel >= (0.8 * df$h2), ], file = y)
    }, x = myfiles, y = newfiles)
```

Comment: Thank you @RichardScriven. But when I run it, I get the following message: 
$CGRM.csv
NULL

Comment: That's the output from `write.csv` when using `mapply()`.  Have a look at the new files and there should be some data in there

Comment: Sorry. My files are dataframe. But it looks like it is not reading.  Thanks.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that you put the sample file in the post. `read.table()` is what you want

Comment: You can use `mapply` rather than `Map`